# Ordering SQL RollUp Output for Top-P-From-Top-Q query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, rollup

I have the following output from the given SQL RollUp query:

```
    SELECT
        COALESCE(name, "Total"),
        COALESCE(event, "Total"),
        SUM(raised) AS money
    FROM money_raised
    GROUP BY name, event WITH ROLLUP
```

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| name   | event  | money     |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 2      | Total  | 9         |
| 1      | a      | 2         |
| 2      | b      | 3         |
| 1      | c      | 4         |
| Total  | Total  | 16        |
| 1      | Total  | 7         |
| 2      | a      | 4         |
| 1      | b      | 1         |
| 2      | c      | 2         |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

How can I extend the query (or re-implement it if you think there's a better approach) to sort the results to get the top p events by total money raised for the top q individuals by total money raised in descending order of both. For example for q = 2 and p = 2 I want the following output.

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| name   | event  | money     |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| 2      | a      | 4         |
| 2      | b      | 3         |
| 1      | c      | 4         |
| 1      | a      | 2         |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Individual "2" is listed first since they raised a total of 9 and then we list their top 2 events, "a" which raised 4 and "b" which raised 3. Then individual "1" is listed since they only raised 7 and have top two events "c" and "a".

Thanks!

I was thinking something along the lines of the below but unsure how to associate each record with its the "total" money raised by its corresponding individual.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(name, "Total"),
        COALESCE(event, "Total"),
        SUM(raised) AS money
    FROM money_raised
    GROUP BY name, event WITH ROLLUP
) 
ORDER BY [...]
```

The original data looked something like the following (assuming I've added up the number correctly):

```
date,   name,   event,      money
1       2       b           1
2       2       b           2
1       1       a           1
3       1       a           1
1       1       c           3
4       2       a           2
3       1       c           1
3       2       a           1
2       1       b           1
6       2       a           1
5       2       c           2
```

Comment: can you provide the original data, before running the query

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the top 2 events of the top 2 indivituals. This suggest window functions, to compute the total money per individual, and then rank the events and individuals.

Here is one approach:

```
select name, event, money
from (
    select m.*,
        dense_rank() over(order by money_for_name desc) rn1,
        dense_rank() over(partition by name order by money desc) rn2
    from (
        select name, event, 
            sum(raised) as money,
            sum(sum(raised)) over(partition by name) money_for_name
        from money_raised
        group by name, event
    ) m
) m
where rn1 <= 2 and rn2 <= 2
order by rn1, rn2
```

The most inner subquery does the aggregation by event and name, and also computes subtotals for each name (`money_for_name`); the next level ranks individuals by total money (`rn1`), and ranks events of each individual (`rn2`). The final step is just filtering on the ranks and ordering the results.

I am not sure if, and how, you want the rollup in the picture here.

Comment: I was hoping by using the rollup I could limit the number of nested queries, and improve the performance, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @DavieRodger: ok, I understand. Window functions are a better tool for this job, I believe.